# Firebase realtime database throwing error in emulator

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase realtime database in my application. None of the APIs are working in my emulator. But the same works in devices. What could be the reason?

The error thrown is

> I/RepoOperation: get for query /Users/ falling back to disk cache after error: Client is offline

Comment: It says the Client is offline. Maybe the internet hasn't been enabled for emulators?

Comment: Did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65927977/android-realtime-database-throws-error-client-is-offline-but-its-not

Comment: @BEAGLE internet is enabled